# WMI query execution thorough powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

Facing below variations when I execute a WMI query from WMI browser and powershell

From WMI Browser

Query:

```
Select Caption  from Win32_TimeZone
```

Output:

```
Caption                                      |  StandardName
[UTC+530]Chennai,Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi     Indian Standard Time
```

From Powershell:

Query:

```
Get-WmiObject -query  "select caption from Win32_Timezone"
```

Ouput: 
[image]

Where is `StandardName` coming from in the WMI browser?

Comment: Use this `Get-Member -Input (Get-WMIObject Win32_Timezone)` to see what properties that class has.

Comment: You can run `Get-WmiObject -query  "select StandardName from Win32_Timezone"` to see the StandardName, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Hi from WMI browser even if we are not giving StandardName its coming in the results and this is happening for all the WMIObject Ex: Win32_process, the query is "select OSName from win32_process" , Result will give both OSName, Handle not understanding what is the logic behind that

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the same results:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Timezone | Select Caption,StandardName
```

or remove the StandardName if not needed.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Timezone | Select Caption
```

Comment: You don't even need the select statement, really.  It just returns a pscustomobject instead of the managementobject wmi returns.

Comment: of course, but it give the same results the OP need

Comment: Hi from WMI browser even if we are not giving StandardName its coming in the results and this is happening for all the WMIObject Ex: Win32_process, the query is "select OSName from win32_process" , Result will give both OSName, Handle not understanding what is the logic behind that